# Spotify error message display in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, spotify, error-code, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I am implementing spotify in my iPhone app using CocoaLibSpotify library.
I need to show the error messages specified in the guideline https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/guidelines-ios/.
Should I need to check the error codes in every places that have spotify library calls or is there any delegate function that called for a spotify error.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many operations will return an `NSError` in their callbacks. When calling those methods, you must check the error and respond appropriately.